# Can I follow a user's activity on a Bugzilla instance?

Tags: user-accounts, tracking, bug-trackers, bugzilla

There's a user who I see active on a bunch of bugs on a Bugzilla instance (= an installation of the bugzilla bug tracker on some website) I'm on. But - I don't see *everything* he's doing...

I know I can statically search for his activity using the Bugzilla search functionality. But - is it possible to somehow be notified whenever he does *anything*, or better yet - for every bug, be notified once when he first performs some action relating to that bug?

Note: I'm not asking from an administrator's perspective, I'm just a regular Bugzilla user.

Comment: [tag:bugzilla] has no tag wiki, and there isn't any other question on Web Apps SE with this tag. Please provide more details about what you mean by "Bugzilla instance". If this is a self-hosted web app, only questions about **using** standard features are on-topic. Questions about installing, configuring, or using custom, extended and non-standard features are off-topic unless they use well-known, formally supported, well-documented plug-ins / add-ons.

Comment: @Rubén: See edit.